# Заполнение массива данными из строки при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript, json

```
"[{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586}]
```

Есть некоторая строка, как вытащить и записать в массив значения varible. Нужно написать регулярное выражение. Может кто-то уже парсил JSON строку?
Т.е массив = [-114.989586,-114.989586,-114.989586]

Comment: почему значение в строке одно, а в массиве их 3? И регулярное выражение тут не нужно. Можно JSON.parse получить объект

Comment: Нужно именно регулярное выражение? `JSON.parse` не подойдет?

Comment: зачем искать легкие пути :DDD

Comment: Как при помощи JSON.parse сформировать массив [-114.989586,-114.989586,-114.989586]???

Comment: вот что у меня есть  success:function (data) {
                     $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(indice, list){
                            list.name;
                });

Comment: может ли list.name записаться в массив 3 раза???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсим `JSON` строку в объект и с помощью [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) вытягиваем массив `varible`'ов:

```js
var jsonString = "[{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586}]"

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var variables = obj.map(i => i.varible);
console.log(variables);
```

`ES5`:

```js
var jsonString = "[{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586}]"

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var variables = obj.map(function(i) { return i.varible; });
console.log(variables);
```

Comment: Ну просто идеально, попробую себе засунуть в код спасибо

Comment: в консоле выводит [{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586},{\"id_index\":1,\"date\":\"2017-05-15\",\"name\":\"Коэффициент текущей ликвидности\",\"varible\":-114.989586}], что это может быть??

Comment: $.ajax({
                  type:'post',
                  url:'Find_By_Year_Quater_Index',
                  data: {year_datapicker:year_datapicker,quater:quater,open:open},
                  response:'json',
                  
                  success:function (data) {
                      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                      var variables = obj.map(i => i.varible);
                      alert(variables);
                   
                   
                    
                    $("#loader").hide(); 
                  }

Comment: @Serjey123 попробуйте `var variables = data.map(i => i.varible);`. Подозреваю, что у вас сразу распаршенный объект приходит...

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению

Comment: @Serjey123 посмотрите в дебаггере, что приходит. Или напишите `console.log(data)` и сделайте скриншот.

Comment: Может это не json?

Comment: ну если перебирать через success:function (data) {
                     $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(indice, list){
                 $("#main_table").append($("<tr>").append("<td id='date'>"+ list.date+"</td>"+"<td id='name'>"+list.name+"</td>"
                            + "<td id ='varible_find'>"+list.varible+"</td>"+"<td id ='unit_find'>"+list.unit+"</td>"));
                }); все нормально выводит

Comment: @Serjey123 ааа, скорее всего у вас не `ES6`. Обновил ответ (Пробуйте нижний вариант)

Comment: помогло спасибо вам огромное!!!